# problem with vb.net doing action for other forms

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 forms, 1 is for control and the other is for display. Its 2 because the 1 for display will consume the whole screen and there's no space for buttons.
Im trying to control form4 using form2 or some other form, navigating a certain webpage in the process.

I have this code for the control:
 but it does not work, what would I do?

```
Form4.WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.animedreaming.com/fairy-tail-episode-19/")
```

Comment: Is it really meant to be localhost?

Comment: Do you know how .NET works? It's basicly all one big form that will get posted. What are you trying to achieve? You are not very clear here.

Comment: @1st post:when he compiles @ IDE, i think so :>

Comment: ive edited it, have a look, if it is still unclear, let me send you a link containing a video that shows what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your meaning you can access one form from another by making a local class along the lines of...

FORM#1 -->

Public Class FORM#1
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

Public Shared Form as FORM#1

Public Sub someAction (byVal someParameter as someKindOfThingy)

' do something

End Sub

End Class

FORM #2 -->

FORM#1.someAction(someParameter)

===================================

There are any number of variations on this basic theme... from declaring a local class in FORM#2 as type FORM#1 through the use of delegates.